# Reset/Recenter spawn objects origin in Unity XR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just starting to study unity so my question may be trivial, but I cannot figure out how to solve my problem.

I am writing an augmented reality application with Unity for smartphones (iOS and Android).

My goal is to have different objects pop up after clicking a button, once I click the button I want my 3D object to show in front of me. Currently once I have the first object pop up, if I move into the space (a few meters further than where I was before), the object will no longer appear in front of me but in the location of the space where I was before.

[image: Hierarchy AR Unity Project - Inspector on XR Origin object]

I am currently using the XR Origin module to manage the projection of objects in space. It is not clear to me how to reset the origin of the objects or reposition the objects in front of me (as they are set in the Unity editor)

[image: Example Scene and object positions]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution but if you have better solution, please write here your proposal.

```
public class ImageRecognition : MonoBehaviour {

    ...
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Button buttonReference;
    ...

    private void Awake() {

        ...
        buttonReference.onClick.AddListener(StartSessionOnClick);
        ...
    }

    private void StartSessionOnClick() {
        Recenter("tagObjectName");
    }

    private void Recenter(objectTagName) {

        var distance = 1.1f;
        var target = GameObject.FindWithTag(objectTagName).transform;
        var rotation = cameraTransform.rotation;
        target.position = cameraTransform.position + cameraTransform.forward * distance;
        target.rotation = new Quaternion( 0.0f, rotation.y, 0.0f, rotation.w );
    }
    ...
}
```

`originTransform` and `cameraTransform` are linked to XROrigin and Main Camera objects. `buttonReference` is linked to my button used to recenter/respawn objects.